# Count of unique items in mongodb documents with Array of Strings

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a problem that seems like it can be solved by some aggregation samples I've seen, but I've not come up with an answer yet.

Basically I have documents like so:

```
{
  date: '2015-01-14 00:00:00.000Z',
  attendees: ['john', 'jane', 'james', 'joanne'],
  groupName: '31'
}
```

And I need to find the unique attendees for a *groupName* and their attendance count. So for example, with the data:

```
{
  date: '2015-01-13 00:00:00.000Z',
  attendees: ['john', 'jane', 'james', 'joanne'],
  groupName: '31'
},
{
  date: '2015-01-14 00:00:00.000Z',
  attendees: ['james', 'joanne'],
  groupName: '31'
},
{
  date: '2015-01-15 00:00:00.000Z',
  attendees: ['joanne'],
  groupName: '31'
}
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
[{
  name: 'joanne',
  count: 3
}, {
  name: 'john',
  count: 1
}, {
  name: 'james',
  count: 2
}]
```

I can't seem to find an aggregation to get this type of result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) => [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$attendees'},
  {$group: {_id: '$attendees', count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$project: {_id:0, name: '$_id', count: '$count'}}
])
```

Comment: This is perfect. I had something something similar, but was missing the $unwind and was not handling $count correctly. Thank you!

My understanding is this:
$unwind gets a unique document for each array item (person).
$group creates a count variable with value 1 and sets the _id to the attendee name and then groups similar items summing each "1" together to yield the count value.
$project maps _id to name and uses the existing count

Comment: $unwind is nothing but denormalising data, i.e splitting an array to objects.